# C/C++ How can I get unique value from 2 arrays?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, unique

I need to get the unique value from 2 int arrays

Duplicate is allowed

There is just one unique value

like :

```
int arr1[3]={1,2,3};
int arr2[3]={2,2,3};
```

and the value i want to get is :

```
int unique[]={1}
```

how can i do this?
im already confused in my 'for' and 'if'
this was not homework

i know how to merge 2 arrays and del duplicate values

but i alse need to know which array have the unique value

plz help me :)

and here is some code i did

```
int arr1[3]={1,2,3}
int arr2[3]={2,2,3}
int arrunique[1];
bool unique = true;
for (int i=0;i!=3;i++)
{

    for (int j=0;j!=3;j++)
    {
    if(arr1[i]==arr2[j])
    {
        unique=false;
        continue;
    }
    else 
    {
        unique=true;
    }
if(unique)
{
arrunique[0]=arr1[i]
break;
}
}

cout << arrunique[0];
```

Comment: Do you want the value(s) in `arr2` that aren't in `arr1`, or all the values in either that aren't in the other (e.g., if `arr2 = {2,3,4}`, do you want just 1, or 1 and 4?

Comment: Post your code so far! Also, have you considered just using [`std::set_difference()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_difference/) on the sorted arrays? (Or, even more likely, [`std::set_symmetric_difference()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_symmetric_difference/)?)

Comment: sort them first. Then, the question will be easy.

Comment: but i need to know where is the unique one , not what value is unique

Comment: @Cameron `set_symmetric_difference` won't work, since duplicate values are allowed.

Comment: Do they need to not be in the other set, unique between the sets or unique within the union of both lists? What I mean is: does `arr1[3]={1,1,1}; arr2[3]={2,2,2};` need to return `{1,1,1,2,2,2}`, `{1,2}` or `{}`?

Comment: @Timothy: Good point. In that case, tossing the arrays into two sets first is probably the easiest solution (eliminates the need to sort, too). In any case, +1 for your answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming:

- You have two arrays of different length,
- The arrays are sorted
- The arrays can have duplicate values in them
- You want to get the list of values that only appear in one of the arrays

  - including their duplicates if present

You can do (untested):

```
// Assuming arr1[], arr2[], and lengths as arr1_length  
int i = 0,j = 0, k = 0;
int unique[arr1_length + arr2_length];

while(i < arr1_length && j < arr2_length) {
   if(arr1[i] == arr2[j]) {
     // skip all occurrences of this number in both lists
     int temp = arr1[i];
     while(i < arr1_length && arr1[i] == temp) i++;
     while(j < arr2_length && arr2[j] == temp) j++;
   } else if(arr1[i] > arr2[j]) {
     // the lower number only occurs in arr2
     unique[k++] = arr2[j++]; 
   } else if(arr2[j] > arr1[i]) {
     // the lower number only occurs in arr1
     unique[k++] = arr1[i++]; 
   }     
}

while(i < arr1_length) {
   // if there are numbers still to read in arr1, they're all unique
   unique[k++] = arr1[i++];
}
while(j < arr2_length) {
   // if there are numbers still to read in arr2, they're all unique
   unique[k++] = arr2[j++];
}
```

Some alternatives:

- If you don't want the duplicates in the `unique` array, then you can skip all occurrences of this number in the relevant list when you assign to the unique array.
- If you want to record the position instead of the values, then maintain two arrays of "unique positions" (one for each input array) and assign the value of `i` or `j` to the corresponding array as appropriate.
- If there's only one unique value, change the assignments into the unique array to return.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, you might also want to look at [set_symmetric_difference()](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/set_symmetric_difference.html) function of the standard library. However, its treatment of duplicate values makes its use a bit tricky, to say the least.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int cmp ( const void *a , const void *b )
{
        return *(int *)a - *(int *)b;
}
int main()
{
int arr1[5] = {5,4,6,3,1};
int arr2[3] = {5, 8, 9};
int unique[8];

qsort(arr1,5,sizeof(arr1[0]),cmp);

printf("\n");

qsort(arr2,3,sizeof(arr2[0]),cmp);

//printf("%d", arr1[0]);
int i = 0;
int k = 0;
int j = -1;

while (i < 5 && k < 3)
{
    if(arr1[i] < arr2[k])
    {
        unique[++j] = arr1[i];
        i++;
    }
    else if (arr1[i] > arr2[k])
    {
        unique[++j] = arr2[k];
        k++;
    }
    else
    {
        i++;
        k++;
    }
}
//int len = j;
int t = 0;
if(i == 5)
{
    for(t = k; t < 3; t++)
        unique[++j] = arr2[t];
}
else
    for(t = i; t < 5; t++)
        unique[++j] = arr2[t];

for(i = 0; i <= j; i++)
    printf("%d ", unique[i]);
return 0;
}
```

This is my codes,though there is a good answer .
I didn't realize the idea that know which array have the unique value.
I also think that the right answer that you chose didn't , either.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version of the algorithm for finding identical elements in sorted arrays on Python in C ++, it works in a similar way

```
def unique_array(array0 : (int), array1 : (int)) -> (int):
index0, index1, buffer = 0, 0, []
while index0 != len(array0) and index1 != len(array1):
    if array0[index0] < array1[index1]:
        buffer.append(array0[index0])
        index0 += 1
    elif array0[index0] > array1[index1]:
        buffer.append(array1[index1])
        index1 += 1
    else:
        index0 += 1; index1 += 1
buffer.extend(array0[index0 : len(array0)])
buffer.extend(array1[index1 : len(array1)])
return buffer
```

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is strictly an [English Q&A only](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange). Posts containing anything else risk being [deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers). Please translate your answer to English only.